# How to call external configuration file data in to the class in c# without ConnectionStrings and appSettingspp

Tags: c#, .net, xml

I am new to c#, I googled to find solution to my problem , but nothing worked for me.
even stack overflow solutions don't worked for me.

I have App.config and email.config file both are in same path

my email.config file contains

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
  <Template>
    <input id="ok" arguments="tetst" />
  </Template>
</configuration>
```

Now I am not able to load data from `arguments` field values in my c# class

there are some solutions in internet and ms forums suggestiong to use connectionStrings and appSettings, which is not need for my case

I tied something like fallowing in my c#

var sys= ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration("email.config");

don't know how to progress

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure if you can read that *email.config* with the ConfigurationManager.
The file contains a Section named Template with some custom keys/value pairs and probably you need a custom class to read that key/value pair

However you can read your file with an XmlDocument class in this way

```
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.Load(@"d:\temp\email.config");
var value = doc.DocumentElement.SelectSingleNode("/configuration/Template/input[@id='ok']")
               .Attributes["arguments"].Value;
```